# Why would AWS Aurora capacity settings not follow the "Pause compute capacity after consecutive minutes of inactivity"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have switched from an AWS MySQL RDS to AWS MySQL Aurora for our Wordpress website because of the "Pause compute capacity after consecutive minutes of inactivity" feature that could lower the costs.

I have set the limit to 5 minutes. Unfortunately, the "Logs and Events" tab show no event thus, the computing capacity is never paused.

I noticed that there are no database connections mutiple times in the days, wouldn't the compute capacity be paused in that situation ?

[image]

[image: maximum value]

Is there a way to pin point why this happens ?

Comment: If this graph is connections, you probably want to look at "minimum" rather than "average" for the most accurate representation.

Comment: THanks for the heads up Michael. I checked the graph again for the 6 last hours with 5 min interval and set to minimum statistic. There were almost no db connetions. Why wouldn't the compute capacity pause ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not thinking correctly when I posted that suggestion.  I should have suggested you look at the *maximum* value.

Comment: Haha, makes sense. Updated my question with maximum value instead. Still the compute value should be paused several times in the last 6 hours. But my Logs and Events tab still sohw no event.

Comment: When you say `There were *almost* no db connections`, why do you say "almost" ?

Comment: I mean there were a few connections, but long moments during which there were none. The computing should be paused 5 minutes after no activity. One interesting thing. There is CPU activity even though there are no DB connection...

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have seen your name around a lot lately, you seem like the expert ! Do you have any idea how I could troubleshoot this problem ? While there are sometimes no database connections, the CPU is constant.